# Fill holes with an area bigger of a specific value in a raster coverage

Tags: raster, grass-gis, regionalization

I want to fill some areas of a raster coverage with a value of my choice. Those areas now contain NODATA values. So, they look like *holes* in my coverage.

I know I could use [r.clump](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.clump.html) function of GRASS, but I don't know how to specify the maximum area. Because if a hole is bigger than that area, I don't want to consider it as hole. Is that even possible with GRASS?

Comment: The [GRASS manual](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/r.mapcalc.html) provides many, many ways to detect and replace (or recategorize) NoData values.